# How to set HTTPONLY to the auth cookie generated by webapp2 auth module?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, webapp2

This is how I set up to use the `auth` token of `webapp2`

```
'webapp2_extras.auth': {
    'cookie_name': 'auth',
    'token_max_age': 24 * 60 * 60,
    'user_attributes': []
},
```

I have checked the documentation but I found no mention of setting other attributes of this cookie. I would like to make sure this cookie is 'HTTPOnly'

How can I set `HTTPOnly` via webapp2 configuration or any other means?

Answer (score 2):

It can be configured in webapp2_extras.sessions:

```
'webapp2_extras.auth': {
  ...
},
'webapp2_extras.sessions': {
   'cookie_args': {
     'httponly': True,
   },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source for '[webapp2_extras.auth](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/_modules/webapp2_extras/auth.html)', you'll see that it does not implement the same session argument options as '[webapp2_extras.sessions](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/_modules/webapp2_extras/sessions.html)'. However it does depend on 'webapp2_extras.sessions', and does set the 'max_age' session argument explicitly (line numbers not present):

```
def set_session(self, user, token=None, token_ts=None, cache_ts=None,
                remember=False, **session_args):
    # ...
    session_args.setdefault('max_age', max_age)
    # Create a new dict or just update user?
    # ...
```

Presumably you could modify the webapp2 source to add this extra session argument here, however I can't comment on any adverse effects from doing so.